# How do I get an "output" of a code to stay on the same page? HTML forms?

Tags: javascript, html, screen

I am a beginner in JavaScript and HTML.

I am writing a code in JavaScript that converts "Infix to Postfix".

The user enters their "desired mathematical expression" into a form (made by html), then presses a button to evaluate the solution of the infix expression.

But the program clears the page before it writes the solution.

I do NOT want the solution to appear on a cleared page. I want it to appear on the original page, in a textbox or anything else. But I can't get the textbox to "output" anything.

Help please? 
Most grateful.

Comment: Can you paste the Javascript (and HTML) code where you try to print the result?

Comment: Iam not sure if I get this straight. You want the result of your conversion to appear without the page refreshing?

Comment: Don't use *input type="submit"*, just use a regular button and hook up the onclick event to call your code.

Comment: Also, don't use `document.write` after the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert text into an existing textbox, you need to do two things.

1. You need to get the DOM element of the textbox.
2. You need to set the right property on the textbox to put the value into it.

There are many ways to get the DOM element of the textbox.  `document.getElementById()` is the simplest.  You put an id="whatever" attribute on your textbox HTML and then use `document.getElementById("whatever")` to get the DOM element.

This is the simplest example:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>​
```

Javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("mytext");
element.value = "This is my text";
```

​
Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/b4mNP/

---

Do NOT try to use `document.write()` after the document has finished loading.  That will just clear the existing document and start writing a new one.

You also have to make sure that you don't have a form that is doing a form submission (as that will also clear the page) and that you're not clicking a link that will go to an href.

Comment: @ jfriend00, I don't quite understand. Can you please clarify? Or write an example?

Comment: @user1910524 - I've added a working example to my answer.  You do NOT use `document.write()` after the document has loaded because that will just clear your existing document and start a new blank one.  Instead, you use DOM functions to manipulate the existing elements on the page.

Comment: @ Steffen Martinsen, yes I do.

Comment: @ jfriend00, is there another way that doesn't involve functions? Can I not in the actual code, tell it to print in the textbox?

Comment: @user1910524 - It's tough to understand what you're asking because you're using odd terminology.  A `function` is code.  So, I don't know why you want code that isn't a function.  If you just want an initial value in the textarea, you can specify that in the HTML with no javascript at all.  Please describe better what the overall problem is that you're trying to solve/implement.  What about my working example does not meet your needs?

Comment: @ jfriend00, I'm trying to implement your idea into my code. But it still doesn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: @user1910524 - I can't help you further without seeing your actual code.  Did you look in the error console to see if you have javascript errors?

Comment: @ jfriend00 , thank you so much. I'm still having trouble getting it into my code. But I got the idea. Thank you.

Comment: @user1910524 - Since you're new to StackOverflow, do you understand that SO is based on a reputation system? You earn reputation points by supplying good answers to other people's questions that get upvoted, by asking good questions that earn votes as good questions and by selecting a best answer for questions you ask. People who supply answers get points when their answers are either upvoted or selected as the best answer. That is part of their reward for helping. If you feel an answer is worthy, you can select it as the best answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.